# UIImagePicker camera screenshot black

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIimagepickerController to show live camera feed on screen. But when I take a screenshot using following code i get black screen.

```
-(UIImage *)getScreenShot{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, 
self.view.opaque, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[ipc.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

return image;
}
```

How can I take screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this **EDIT**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(takeSreenShot) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)takeSreenShot
{

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    }

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

    // grab reference to our window
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

    // transfer content into our context
    [window.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    UIImage *screengrab = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // save screengrab to Camera Roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screengrab, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: I tried it, But still I get a black screen on iOS 11.2.2.

Comment: Try this EDIT. Hope it helps!

Comment: I call it on view controller touches begin delegate

Comment: I need the screenshot with whatever is visible on screen through camera feed!